# How to divide/distribute books to boxes

Tags: ms-access

I have a list that shows how many books we have for each PO No. (Sorted by PO No.) Like below:

```
**LIST 1:**

**PO No**       **TOTAL BOOKS**
PO-0001              12
PO-0002              15
PO-0003              26
```

Now I would like to distribute/divide these books to boxes and each box gets maximum 10 books. Like below list:

```
LIST 2:

**BOX NO**      **BOOKS**       **PO NO**
  0001         BOOK 1~10        PO-0001
  0002         BOOK 11~12       PO-0001
  0002         BOOK 1~8         PO-0002
  0003         BOOK 9~15        PO-0002
  0003         BOOK 1~3         PO-0003
  0004         BOOK 4~13        PO-0003
  0005         BOOK 14~23       PO-0003
```

How I can produce automatically list 2 from list 1 by query or coding?

Comment: Why does `Box No 0002 Book 1~8 PO-0002` not have books `1-10`?

Comment: you are right i have made a mistake (i was in hurry) i have to change list2

Comment: sorry list 2 was ok, because total books of po-0001 was 12 books, when we put 10 books in box-0001, we have 2 books remain from 12 books, so we put these 2 books (book 11~12) in box 0002+book 1~8 from po-0002

Comment: Okay - understood. Give me a minute

Comment: Does `**BOOKS**` need to be formatted like `BOOK 1~10` ? Why can't it just say 10? The ``PO NO` will give you all the information, and then you can perform aggregation on the table and not have to use VBA to search strings/substrings

Comment: actually i have book no for each book. for excample for po-0001 that we have 12 different books, bookno 1/12, book no 2/12, ....so i would like to know start bookno for each po in each box, format is not important for me, any list that shows which books contains.

Comment: Well, you're only making it harder on yourself by formatting the BOOKS records like that because you have to search the substring of the prior records for the PO Box instead of retrieving an integer.

Comment: i need start book no and End book no that we have for each pono in each box. start book no and end bookno are integer. after i can have these fields in my list i can make a report with any format.

Comment: Okay I see what you're saying. That's a little annoying haha

Comment: thank you very much, please do not be hurry i am waiting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one guy solved my question, so for closing my question I add the answer as below:

create a new table "PackingList" with fields  "BoxNo" (Long), "PONo" (Text), "TotalBooks" (Long), "StartNo" (Long) and "EndNo" (Long). The Primary Key is on (BoxNo, PONo).

Then the code below should give you the result.

```
Public Sub PackBooks()

 Dim db  As DAO.Database
Dim bk  As DAO.Recordset ' Books
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

 Dim BoxNo       As Long ' No of box currently being packed
 Dim BooksInBox  As Long ' How many books are already in the box that is   currently being packed
 Dim BooksPacked As Long ' How many books are already packed for the current PONo
 Dim Remaining   As Long ' How many books remain to be packed for the current PONo
 Dim BooksToPack As Long ' How many books are to be packed for the current PONo into the current box
 Dim StartNo     As Long
 Dim EndNo       As Long

Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("", "Delete * From PackingList") ' start with an empty packing list
 qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
 qdf.Close
 Set bk = db.OpenRecordset("Select * From Books Order By PONo")
 If Not bk.EOF Then
BoxNo = 1
BooksInBox = 0

 Do While Not bk.EOF
  BooksPacked = 0
  EndNo = 0

  Do While BooksPacked < bk!TotalBooks
     Remaining = bk!TotalBooks - BooksPacked
     If Remaining >= 10 - BooksInBox Then
        BooksToPack = 10 - BooksInBox
     Else
        BooksToPack = Remaining
     End If
     StartNo = EndNo + 1
     EndNo = StartNo + BooksToPack - 1

     Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("", " Insert Into PackingList (BoxNo, PONo, TotalBooks, StartNo, EndNo) " & _
                                     " Values (" & BoxNo & ", '" & bk!PONo & "', " & bk!TotalBooks & ", " & StartNo & ", " & EndNo & ")")
     qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
     qdf.Close

     BooksPacked = BooksPacked + BooksToPack
     BooksInBox = BooksInBox + BooksToPack
     If BooksInBox = 10 Then
        BoxNo = BoxNo + 1
        BooksInBox = 0
      End If
    Loop
    bk.MoveNext
 Loop
End If

 Set qdf = Nothing
  bk.Close
  Set bk = Nothing
  db.Close
  Set db = Nothing

 End Sub
```